# Sync keyboard shortcuts for ipad with iCloud

Tags: ipad, keyboard, icloud

I have some useful text expander shortcuts on my MacBook Pro and I would like to get them synced with the shortcuts on my ipad. That way I don't have to maintain the same shortcut list in 2 places. Does anyone know how to do do this? I also know that there are text expander apps for ipad, but is any of them importing the shortcuts from iCloud?

Comment: I checked the options now and I'm syncing everything except Mail, Calendars and Photos. 
Documents & data and Safari were off as well, but I turned them on now... Hope this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by Going to Settings > iCloud and selecting to sync Documents & data